# rearranging rows in a table using awk

Tags: awk

I have a table with several hundred lines:

```
a1 
a2 
a3 
a4 
b1 
b2 
b3 
b4 
c1 
c2 
c3 
c4
... etc.
```

I want to return it in the following order:

```
a1
b1
c1
d1
a2
b2
c2
d2
a3
b3
c3
```

The script below works to select the first block of lines:

```
$ awk '{if(NR==1||NR%4==1)print}'
```

But how can I loop it to do it for the whole file?

Comment: Is it always two characters on each line?

Comment: no, actually it is a table with numerous columns. the first column is like shown in my example.

Comment: So, we can assume that the first column is two characters?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort` to do the sorting instead. Specifically you can tell `sort` to do a general sort, `g` which handles the sorting of letters and numbers. We can control which character in the string we want to do the sorting on by telling `sort` using the `X.Y` notation instead of the more typical `X,Y` notation.

For example:

```
$ sort -k1.2g file
a1
b1
c1
a2
b2
c2
a3
b3
c3
a4
b4
c4
```

Sort options:

```
  -k, --key=KEYDEF
          sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
  -g, --general-numeric-sort
         compare according to general numerical value

  KEYDEF is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position, where F is
  a field number and C a character  position in the field; both are origin 1,
  and the stop position defaults to the line's end.  If neither -t nor -b is 
  in effect, characters in a field are counted from the beginning of the 
  preceding whitespace.  OPTS is one or  more  single-letter ordering options
  [bdfgiMhnRrV],  which  override  global ordering options for that key.  If 
  no key is given, use the entire line as the key.
```

Comment: thank you for attention to my problem, but it does not work for my case, because in several lines the letter-number combinations repeat and I get something like a1,a1,a1,b1,b1,b1... I think it's because my description of the task is too generic.

Comment: @kate - then please update your Q with actual real data, otherwise we cannot help further.

Answer (score 0):

If the "step" is always small (in your case, 4) then a quick'n'dirty way might be to simply read the file that many times and pick out the records at each offset - e.g.

```
awk 'FNR==1 {k++} !((FNR-k)%4)' file file file file
a1 
b1 
c1 
a2 
b2 
c2 
a3 
b3 
c3 
a4 
b4 
c4
```

or, equivalently, using GNU Awk (with its `BEGINFILE` rule):

```
gawk 'BEGINFILE{k++} !((FNR-k)%4)' file file file file
```